# 405 Method Not Allowed - AngularJS HTTP

Tags: php, angularjs, http, httpresponse, slim

i cannot see why this is happening:

**AngularJS:**

```
$http.post("/api/favorite", {
         params: {
             "param1": containerId
     }})
```

**PHP(Slim Framwork):**

```
$app->post('/api/favorite', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    echo "testPostmanPat";
});
```

**Both are POST and even the header:**
[image]

**Server Log:**

> INFO     2017-11-28 14:13:11,365 module.py:821] api: "**GET**
>   /api/favorite HTTP/1.1" 405 556

Cannot find out WHY this is happening? im getting **405 error** even if http is POST and server using POST...?

**General Info:**
* Localhost
* Google App Engine
* Middleware: gulp (gulp-api-proxy)
* Frontend: AngularJS
* Backend: PHP (Slim Micro Framework)

Comment: for post method you can not use params

Comment: What can i use then @DeepKakkar to send params? Are not POST made to send this?

Comment: try so ` var  yourParams = {param1: value}  $http({
    url: "your url",
    method: "POST",
    params: yourParams})`

Comment: Did not work, still same error @Beny

Comment: take a look here i think this is the way you need to get param in Slim [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408113/slim-framework-2-0-0-unable-to-use-params-with-get)

Comment: The problem is not getting the param in Slim but rather the HTTP responsecode 405. If i just have an echo i still cant be able to produce it on client side